# navigator.mediaDevices is null on iOS with Chrome 62?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia

Since latest version of Chrome 62, only under iOS 11 devices, when I try using `navigator.mediaDevices` - it's null. Nothing in the documentation suggests this functionality was removed.

In the meantime I opened a [bug under Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=783220), but this is both critical and strange.

Anyone come across this issue? Any ideas?

Comment: does navigator.getUserMedia and/or navigator.webkitGetUserMedia exist? This is iOS so will be webkit under the hood?

Comment: @PhilippHancke Nope, none of them exists. It worked in version 61...

Comment: looks like guido has you covered in that bug.

Comment: @PhilippHancke Voting up my question would be appreciated, I want to speed things up, we have a prod. issue.

Comment: done. I'd recommend checking webrtc support by verifying both GUM and RTCPeerConnection are available. Lets see how quickly this gets solved...

Comment: @PhilippHancke Opened a bug in Apple too. Let's hope this is resolved quickly. Thanks for your help buddy.